# Azure web app deployment have error "Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred."

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-deployment

I am deploying an web app and It give me an error like:

```
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8da2073577e7c44 --compress-destination-dir -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20211207.1, Commit: 46633df49cc8fbe9718772a3c894df221273b2af, ReleaseTagName: 20211207.1

Build Operation ID: |k0MN7QhgbkY=.5fbefdfd_
Repository Commit : 6bc0cf64-6a80-4b53-a94d-605798c20ce9

Detecting platforms...
Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred.
Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred.\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8da2073577e7c44 --compress-destination-dir -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log
```

Can anybody tell me how do I solve this problem

Comment: Try adding logs of your error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a VNet integration then suggest to disconnect and then publish.

See similar issue here: [Detecting platforms... Error: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/971)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing unused config variables. In my case I was migrating from Heroku and I had a DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC variable that wasn't used in my app. After removing it the error went away.